# Permission denied - /app/public/javascripts/fancy_box.js Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fancybox

I am trying to deploy my application on Heroku. I managed to get to this point but it crashed on the Fancybox.js call.
I have no idea what this means. Can someone help out?

THanks in advance.

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Permission denied - /app/public/javascripts/fancy_box.js) on line #10 of app/views/layouts/board.html.erb:
    2011-03-31T09:02:04-07:00 app[web.1]: 7:    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "reset", "style", "subscription", "form-style", "style-admin" %> 
    2011-03-31T09:02:04-07:00 app[web.1]: 8:    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    2011-03-31T09:02:04-07:00 app[web.1]: 9:    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    2011-03-31T09:02:04-07:00 app[web.1]: 10:    <%= include_fancy_box %>
    2011-03-31T09:02:04-07:00 app[web.1]: 11: <%=javascript_include_tag 'jquery.form', 'upload' %>
```

Comment: Does `/app/public/javascripts/fancy_box.js` exist?

Comment: Good point. My app runs on my local and loads all of the scripts for fancy box with the line <%= include_fancy_box %>. To just test it out I put the fancybox scripts in the javascripts directory and then called each one on the layout. I will test that out and see if it works. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

include_fancy_box essentially writes out a lot of javscript_include_tag:

```
    def include_fancy_box(*args)
        content = javascript_include_tag('jquery.fancy_box/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js',
                                         'jquery.fancy_box/jquery.easing.1.3.js',

                                         'jquery.fancy_box/load_fancybox', 
                                         :cache => "fancy_box")
        content << "\n#{stylesheet_link_tag('jquery.fancybox.css')}" 
end
```

If these js files don't exist then you'll have an issue as you can't write to file system on heroku. I suggest you ensure that the files are in javascript folder before you push to heroku